# Deployed war in tomcat 7 not running (GWT 2.5.1, Spring 3.1, JPA 2.1,hibernate 3.6.1)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, gwt

Project is running well in eclipse but it doesn't running in tomcat 7 after deploy.

**Eclipse Log :**

```
1955 [main] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
2982 [main] INFO org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Bean 'sessionFactory' of type [class org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2998 [main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@19e62cf: defining beans [org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,sessionFactory,txmanager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,dataSource,co.orcasys.ehat2.inventory.server.dao.impl.BranchDaoImpl#0,co.orcasys.ehat2.inventory.server.dao.impl.CategoryDaoImpl#0,co.orcasys.ehat2.inventory.server.dao.impl.ContactAddressDaoImpl#0,co.orcasys.ehat2.inventory.server.dao.impl.StockAdjustmentDaoImpl#0,co.orcasys.ehat2.inventory.server.dao.impl.StockLocationDaoImpl#0,co.orcasys.ehat2.inventory.server.dao.impl.VendorMasterDaoImpl#0,co.orcasys.ehat2.inventory.server.dao.impl.ProductDaoImpl#0,co.orcasys.ehat2.inventory.server.dao.impl.IndentDaoImpl#0,co.orcasys.ehat2.inventory.server.dao.impl.FormDaoImpl#0,co.orcasys.ehat2.inventory.server.dao.impl.IngredientDaoImpl#0,co.orcasys.ehat2.inventory.server.dao.impl.ManufacturerDaoImpl#0,co.orcasys.ehat2.inventory.server.dao.impl.PackingDaoImpl#0,co.orcasys.ehat2.inventory.server.dao.impl.UOMDaoImpl#0,co.orcasys.ehat2.inventory.server.dao.impl.LoginDaoImpl#0,co.orcasys.ehat2.inventory.server.dao.impl.ShelfDaoImpl#0,co.orcasys.ehat2.inventory.server.dao.impl.PurchaseEnquireDaoImpl#0,co.orcasys.ehat2.inventory.server.dao.impl.GRNDaoImpl#0,co.orcasys.ehat2.inventory.server.dao.impl.PurchaseOrderDaoImpl#0,branchServiceImpl,categoryServiceImpl,contactAddressServiceImpl,stockAdjustmentServiceImpl,stockLocationServiceImpl,vendorMasterServicesImpl,productServiceImpl,formServiceImpl,indentServiceImpl,ingredientServiceImpl,manufacturerServiceImpl,packingServiceImpl,uomServiceImpl,loginService,shelfServiceImpl,purchaseEnquireServiceImpl,grnServiceImpl,ginServiceImpl,purchaseOrderServiceImpl,org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTHandler#0,viewResolver,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@8b9ff2
3199 [main] INFO org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager - Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@1c8142b] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
3527 [main] INFO org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTHandler - Mapped URL path [/branchService] onto handler of type [class org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTRPCServiceExporter]
3527 [main] INFO org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTHandler - Mapped URL path [/categoryService] onto handler of type [class org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTRPCServiceExporter]
3527 [main] INFO org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTHandler - Mapped URL path [/contactAddressService] onto handler of type [class org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTRPCServiceExporter]
3527 [main] INFO org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTHandler - Mapped URL path [/indentService] onto handler of type [class org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTRPCServiceExporter]
3527 [main] INFO org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTHandler - Mapped URL path [/stockAdjustmentService] onto handler of type [class org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTRPCServiceExporter]
3527 [main] INFO org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTHandler - Mapped URL path [/stockLocationService] onto handler of type [class org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTRPCServiceExporter]
3527 [main] INFO org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTHandler - Mapped URL path [/vendorMasterServices] onto handler of type [class org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTRPCServiceExporter]
3527 [main] INFO org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTHandler - Mapped URL path [/productService] onto handler of type [class org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTRPCServiceExporter]
3527 [main] INFO org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTHandler - Mapped URL path [/formService] onto handler of type [class org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTRPCServiceExporter]
3527 [main] INFO org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTHandler - Mapped URL path [/ingredientService] onto handler of type [class org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTRPCServiceExporter]
3527 [main] INFO org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTHandler - Mapped URL path [/manufacturerService] onto handler of type [class org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTRPCServiceExporter]
3527 [main] INFO org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTHandler - Mapped URL path [/packingService] onto handler of type [class org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTRPCServiceExporter]
3527 [main] INFO org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTHandler - Mapped URL path [/uomService] onto handler of type [class org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTRPCServiceExporter]
3527 [main] INFO org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTHandler - Mapped URL path [/loginService] onto handler of type [class org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTRPCServiceExporter]
3528 [main] INFO org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTHandler - Mapped URL path [/shelfService] onto handler of type [class org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTRPCServiceExporter]
3528 [main] INFO org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTHandler - Mapped URL path [/purchasEnquiryService] onto handler of type [class org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTRPCServiceExporter]
3528 [main] INFO org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTHandler - Mapped URL path [/grnService] onto handler of type [class org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTRPCServiceExporter]
3528 [main] INFO org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTHandler - Mapped URL path [/ginService] onto handler of type [class org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTRPCServiceExporter]
3528 [main] INFO org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTHandler - Mapped URL path [/purchaseOrder] onto handler of type [class org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTRPCServiceExporter]
3865 [main] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'gwt': initialization completed in 3565 ms
```

**Tomcat Log :**

```
4495 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
4496 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Bean 'sessionFactory' of type [class org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
4514 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4a897c: defining beans [org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,sessionFactory,txmanager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,dataSource]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@17d6c1
4577 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager - Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@1a8c064] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
5017 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'gwt': initialization completed in 3135 ms
```

**Using Libraries**

Spring 3.1
GWT-SL 1.1

Comment: Looks OK so far. What makes you think it does not work?

Comment: Found solution, actually its all correct but problem was with war building. thank you sorencito